# weightstats.ztest vs hand calculation

Tags: python, statsmodels, hypothesis-test

I am comparing my z-score result from `weightstats.ztest` and hand calculation and get slightly different result, z_package=-12.636 and z_handbook=-13.019.

The z_package is determined by `z_package, p = weightstats.ztest(data1, data2)` were sample size `data1` is 574 and `data2` is 1026.

The z_handbook is determined by following code:

```
y1 = np.array(data1).mean()
y2 = np.array(data2).mean()


s1 = np.array(data1)).std()
s2 = np.array(data2).std()

n1 = len(data1)
n2 = len(data2)

se = math.sqrt(s1**2/n1+s2**2/n2)

dy = y1-y2

z_handbook = (dy-0)/se
```

I have tried to read about how `weightstats.ztest` calculate the z-score but cannot find any good explanation . Does anyone have a clue where the z-scores differs?

Comment: one item, but I don't know if that's all. numpy std uses ddof=0 by default. Try `.std(ddof=1)`

Comment: second issue: `se` can be pooled under the assumption that variances are equal, or assumed unequal as in your example.

Comment: @Josef the `.std(ddof=1)` didn't give any difference unfortunately. Yes my hand calculation assume that variances are unqeual but the package assume it is equal I think. This is very annoying